# External harddrive enclosure not recognized by MacOS

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-disk

I have an external hard drive enclosure, which contains two 3.5'' HDDs in a Raid 1.
Windows and Ubuntu are playing nice with it, however, my MacBook (13.2.1) does not recognize it. It isn't even showing up in the Disks utility, let alone in Finder.

The drive is formatted with exFAT, since NTFS is apparently read-only for MacOS.

I am very unfamiliar with MacOS, so please treat this as a total newbie question.

Comment: How is this drive formatted?

Comment: It is formatted with exFAT, since I want it to be compatible with Windows

Comment: Ahhh… ExFAT doesn’t lay nice with macOS.  The best option is to copy the data from the ext. drive to a  computer, use macOS to format with FAT32 then copy everything back.  FAT32 will work everywhere